# Make primary key and unique id as foriegn key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follows:

**UserProfile**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_PROFILE (
  id                BIGINT       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id           BIGINT       NOT NULL,      
  name              VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  username          VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  mobile            BIGINT       NOT NULL,      
  description       VARCHAR(100),
  created_date      DATETIME,
  modified_date     DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (user_id)
);
```

**UserDescriptionHistory**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_DESCRIPTION_HISTORY (
  id           BIGINT        NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id      BIGINT        NOT NULL,
  description  VARCHAR(100),
  dt_datetime  DATETIME      NOT NULL   DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USER_PROFILE (id)  
);
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE UserProfile**

```
CREATE TABLE `CYCLOS_USER_PROFILE` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobile` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `mobile` (`mobile`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

I read that the best practice is to reference pk from the parent table. But I also need the unique constraint from the parent table which is the user_id. So can I reference both pk and unique constraints on foreign key? If yes, how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need 2 columns (`id` and `user_id`) in the `user_profile` table? The cleanest option is to have only one. Whether it is `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE NOT NULL` doesn't matter much.

Comment: It is a legacy code. I do not know why two columns have been created. Anyway at present I have implemented as per pk. But I would like to know whether I can create an fk constraint using UNIQUE.

Comment: Yes, you can. No problem at all

Comment: Could you please tell how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first table, `user_profile` has two unique constraints, the `PRIMARY KEY` on `(id)` and the `UNIQUE` on the non-nullable `(user_id)`.

That makes it possible to reference either of them in `FOREIGN KEY` constraints from other tables. You can use what you have, to reference the PK:

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USER_PROFILE (id)
```

or, to reference the UNIQUE column:

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USER_PROFILE (user_id)
```

There is no need to reference both of them.

Comment: If I refer to UNIQUE field as per the second method I get this error: `Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: It works when I try it in dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4fc01532f2c27e57cb32a5d77683b08

Comment: I am still getting the same error in mysql in my system.

Comment: And you are using the exact statement that you posted, only changing the `REFERENCES USER_PROFILE (id)` to `REFERENCES USER_PROFILE (user_id)` in the FK?

Comment: If you have no data in the history table, drop it first, then try again the CREATE TABLE. But it's likely a comma missing or some other minor thing.

Comment: When I run the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` I get the following latest foreign key error `Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint. Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.` This happens only with the UNIQUE ID.

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE USER_PROFILE ;` and add the output in the question.

Comment: Added. In this the UNIQUE KEY is mobile. Is that the problem?

Comment: Off course. You can only reference columns that have either a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint. `(user_id)` is not, so you can't reference it.

Comment: Oh ok. I was just seeing the code for create table. In that the UNIQUE KEY was user_id. I did not know that it was changed later. From next time I should check the history of changes of a table before asking here!